# Trouble Naming a td in css

Tags: html, css

I have been working on this for a while. What I need to know is can I add a name to a td and have it called up properly site wide using css?

So far I can't get it to work. I have a webpage at:

```
http://www.integratedresourcemgmt.com/trevor-smith-magazine/testpg1.htm
```

It contains the style sheet: 
    
    href="http://www.integratedresourcemgmt.com/stylesbaa.css">

I am trying to edit the last line of the style sheet i.e.:

```
.col2 { background-image:url("curvebak.png"); background-position: top
right; background-repeat: no-repeat}
```

Where my td is named: .col2

So far I can't get the image to display. I have it working in html on a page at:

```
http://www.integratedresourcemgmt.com/trevor-smith-magazine/index.htm
```

using the following in the  section of the page:

```
<style>
.TheClassName {
background-image: url(curvebak.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top left
}

</style>
```

and then in the td contains the image i.e.:

```
<td class="TheClassName" width="38" valign="top" height="592" 
background="curvebak.png">&nbsp;</td>
```

I know I am doing something wrong in my first example, I am just wondering what? Or if it is even possible to have a Style sheet work on all pages of a website (actually I know this is possible) but I guess I need to figure out how to correctly name everything so I can try to find a way that I don't have to edit each page of my website, which I will do if I have to. I am just trying to learn this. Thanks in advance for any advice. :)

Comment: The image shows up for me. have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Yes you can add a class to a td, create a simplified example in http://jsfiddle.net of your problem currently. I am not even sure what to look for in your site

Comment: I think after many hours, with all of your help, there really is no way to edit just the style sheet and not each page. Some sort of reference in the page itself has to be made to call out to the style or however it is set up. In my first round of attemps at this I came across some coding that could be written where it was clear from an external oject/style sheet or java where using something like: TD. +td +td would actually locate the table and row externally. I may take one more look at that unless anyone has some ideas. Thank you  so much.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are running into is that although your `td` has a `name` attribute set to `col2`, but you are trying to select it by class.

My suggestion (which you are doing in your second example) is to add a class and reference it by class.

Otherwise, the following would work:

```
td[name="col2"] {
    background-image:url("curvebak.png");
    background-position: top right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```

Comment: Well now I am lost. I guess I don't understand how  to add a class and reference it by class. I have tried several things. The most recent which, I am sure is wrong, is:    .td "name="col2""{ background-image: url(curvebak.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: right top}

Comment: To reference an id with css, it would be `#yourId`. To reference a class, it would be `.yourClass`. To reference an attribute, like name, it would be: `[name=yourNameValue]`.

Comment: Well I am pretty sure I have tried all of those without luck. So I think, I fundamentally do not understand. I am working between using Wordpad and Dreamweavers' Styles editor, both of which, I am pretty sure don't like each other. I am not sure where to post my code examples in and Add Comment on this forum so I was thinking of Answering my question, but that did not look right?

Comment: If you checkout [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nc6jmemy/), you'll see your `<td name=col2>`  getting the css

Comment: I think after many hours, with all of your help, there really is no way to edit just the style sheet and not each page. s